# BitTorrent peer protocol messages

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, networking

I'm writing a BitTorrent client. Part of the protocol is an exchange of length-prefixed messages between peers. The forms of these messages are described in the [official specification](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html#all-non-keepalive-messages-start-with-a-single-byte-which-gives-their-type) and also in the [unofficial specification](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Messages) that is maintained by the community. This is my code for writing out this messages into a stream. I'm currently using C++11 as supported by GCC 4.6.

I have a header file:

```
#ifndef MESSAGE_HPP
#define MESSAGE_HPP

#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

namespace greed {
    // This type defines all the message types and the matching codes
    // It uses C++11's ability to define an enum's underlying type
    enum message_type : signed char
    {
    // this keep_alive as negative is a hack I'm not too happy with
        keep_alive      = -1,
        choke           = 0,
        unchoke         = 1,
        interested      = 2,
        not_interested  = 3,
        have            = 4,
        bitfield        = 5,
        request         = 6,
        piece           = 7,
        cancel          = 8
    };

    // There are three basic kinds of messages
    // These three basic templates are used in CRTP below
    //  - messages with no payload: these contain only the length
    //         and the type code
    template <message_type Type>
        struct no_payload_message
        {
            std::ostream& put(std::ostream& os) const;
        };

    //  - messages with a fixed-length payload: these contain the length,
    //         the type code, and a payload of a fixed-length, that is
    //         determined by the message type.
    template <typename Message>
        struct fixed_payload_message
        {
            std::ostream& put(std::ostream& os) const;
        };

    //  - messages with a payload of variable length: these contain the length,
    //         the type code, and the payload.
    template <typename Message>
        struct variable_payload_message
        {
            std::ostream& put(std::ostream& os) const;
        };

    // A template definition for messages, templated on the message type.
    template <message_type Type>
        struct message {};

    // A specialization for keep-alives, which are special messages that
    // consist of a single zero byte.
    template<>
        struct message<keep_alive>
        {
        public:
            std::ostream& put(std::ostream& os) const;
        };

    // Specializations for the no-payload messages types
    // The only difference between these is the message type.
    template <>
        struct message<choke> : public no_payload_message<choke> {};

    template <>
        struct message<unchoke> : public no_payload_message<unchoke> {};

    template <>
        struct message<interested> : public no_payload_message<interested> {};

    template <>
        struct message<not_interested> : public no_payload_message<not_interested> {};

    // The specializations for fixed-length payload messages contain:
    //  - appropriate constructors
    //  - a type that defines the format of the message (data_type)
    //  - a function that returns the data (data)
    // These are used by the fixed_payload_message template
    template<>
        struct message<have> : public fixed_payload_message<message<have>>
        {
        public:
            message() = delete;
            explicit message(unsigned index);

            struct data_type;
            data_type data() const;

        private:
            unsigned index;
        };

    // The specializations for variable-length payload messages contain:
    //  - appropriate constructors
    //  - a type that defines the format of the message (data_type)
    //  - a function that returns the variable payload (payload)
    //  - a function that writes out the parts of the message that are not variable (init)
    // These are used by the variable_payload_message template
    template<>
        struct message<bitfield> : public variable_payload_message<message<bitfield>>
        {
        public:
            message() = delete;
            explicit message(std::string bits);

            const std::string payload() const;

            struct data_type;
            void init(char* ptr) const;

        private:
            std::string bits;
        };

    template<>
        struct message<request> : public fixed_payload_message<message<request>>
        {
        public:
            message() = delete;
            message(unsigned index, unsigned begin, unsigned length);

            struct data_type;
            data_type data() const;

        private:
            unsigned index;
            unsigned begin;
            unsigned length;
        };

    template<>
        struct message<piece> : public variable_payload_message<message<piece>>
        {
        public:
            static const message_type id = piece;

            message() = delete;
            message(unsigned index, unsigned begin, std::string block);

            const std::string payload() const;

            struct data_type;
            void init(char* ptr) const;

        private:
            unsigned index;
            unsigned begin;
            std::string block;
        };

    template<>
        struct message<cancel> : public fixed_payload_message<message<cancel>>
        {
        public:
            message() = delete;
            message(unsigned index, unsigned begin, unsigned length);

            struct data_type;
            data_type data() const;

        private:
            unsigned index;
            unsigned begin;
            unsigned length;
        };

    // A simple type trait that determines if a type is a message type
    template <typename NonMesssage>
        struct is_message : std::false_type {};
    template <message_type Type>
        struct is_message<message<Type>> : std::true_type {};

    // Implementation of operator<< for all message types
    // This requires the put member function
    template <typename Message>
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, typename std::enable_if<is_message<Message>::value,const Message&>::type message);
}

#endif
```

And an implementation file:

```
#include "message.hpp"
// this header contains the hton function
#include "util.hpp"

#include <memory>
#include <new>

namespace greed {
    // simple implementation of operator<< for messages
    template <typename Message>
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Message& message) {
            return message.put(os);
        }

    // implementation of no-payload message base class
    template <message_type Type>
        std::ostream& no_payload_message<Type>::put(std::ostream& os) const {
            // make sure this struct is not padded or anything
            // this is a gcc attribute, I'll change this when there is
            // support for the C++11 attribute alignas
            struct __attribute__ ((packed)) data_type {
                unsigned len;
                message_type type;
            };
            // hton is a function that converts from host-endianness to network-endianness
            data_type buffer = { hton(sizeof(data_type)-sizeof(data_type::len)), Type }; // lay out the length and the message type
            return os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buffer), sizeof(data_type)); // write it
        }

    // implementation of fixed-length payload message base class
    template <typename Message>
        std::ostream& fixed_payload_message<Message>::put(std::ostream& os) const {
            auto buffer = static_cast<const Message*>(this)->data(); // get the data from the derived class
            return os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buffer), sizeof(buffer)); // write it
        }

    // implementation of variable-length payload message base class
    template <typename Message>
        std::ostream& variable_payload_message<Message>::put(std::ostream& os) const {
            typedef typename Message::data_type header_type;

            auto m = static_cast<const Message*>(this);
            const auto payload = m->payload(); // get the payload
            const auto data_type_size = sizeof(header_type)+payload.size(); // get the total size
            std::unique_ptr<char[]> mem(new char[data_type_size]); // allocate a buffer for it
            m->init(mem.get()); // write out the fixed-length portion
            std::copy(payload.begin(), payload.end(), mem.get()+sizeof(header_type)); // copy the payload to the buffer
            return os.write(mem.get(), data_type_size); // write it
        }

    std::ostream& message<keep_alive>::put(std::ostream& os) const {
        return os.put(0); // keep-alives are just a simple zero byte
    }

    message<have>::message(unsigned index) : index(index) {}
    struct __attribute__ ((packed)) message<have>::data_type{
        unsigned len;
        message_type type;
        unsigned index;
    };
    // have message data
    message<have>::data_type message<have>::data() const {
        return data_type{ hton(sizeof(data_type)-sizeof(data_type::len)), have, hton(index) };
    }

    message<bitfield>::message(std::string bits) : bits(bits) {}
    struct __attribute__ ((packed)) message<bitfield>::data_type {
        unsigned len;
        message_type type;
    };
    // bitfield message payload
    const std::string message<bitfield>::payload() const {
        return bits;
    }
    void message<bitfield>::init(char* ptr) const {
        // construct a new message<bitfield>::data_type in place
        new(ptr) data_type{ hton(sizeof(data_type)-sizeof(data_type::len)+bits.size()), bitfield };
    }

    message<request>::message(unsigned index, unsigned begin, unsigned length) : index(index), begin(begin), length(length) {}
    struct __attribute__ ((packed)) message<request>::data_type {
        unsigned len;
        message_type type;
        unsigned index;
        unsigned begin;
        unsigned length;
    };
    // request message data
    message<request>::data_type message<request>::data() const {
        return data_type{ hton(sizeof(data_type)-sizeof(data_type::len)), request, hton(index), hton(begin), hton(length) };
    }

    message<piece>::message(unsigned index, unsigned begin, std::string block) : index(index), begin(begin), block(block) {}
    struct __attribute__ ((packed)) message<piece>::data_type {
        unsigned len;
        message_type type;
        unsigned index;
        unsigned begin;
    };
    const std::string message<piece>::payload() const {
        return block;
    }
    void message<piece>::init(void* ptr) const {
        // construct a new message<piece>::data_type in place
        new(ptr) data_type{ hton(sizeof(data_type)-sizeof(data_type::len)+block.size()), piece, index, begin };
    }

    message<cancel>::message(unsigned index, unsigned begin, unsigned length) : index(index), begin(begin), length(length) {}
    struct __attribute__ ((packed)) message<cancel>::data_type {
        unsigned len;
        message_type type;
        unsigned index;
        unsigned begin;
        unsigned length;
    };
    // cancel message data
    message<cancel>::data_type message<cancel>::data() const {
        return data_type{ hton(sizeof(data_type)-sizeof(data_type::len)), cancel, hton(index), hton(begin), hton(length) };
    }

    // explicit template instantiations for all message types
    template struct message<keep_alive>;
    template struct message<choke>;
    template struct message<unchoke>;
    template struct message<interested>;
    template struct message<not_interested>;
    template struct message<have>;
    template struct message<bitfield>;
    template struct message<request>;
    template struct message<piece>;
    template struct message<cancel>;

    template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const message<keep_alive>& message);
    template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const message<choke>& message);
    template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const message<unchoke>& message);
    template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const message<interested>& message);
    template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const message<not_interested>& message);
    template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const message<have>& message);
    template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const message<bitfield>& message);
    template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const message<request>& message);
    template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const message<piece>& message);
    template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const message<cancel>& message);
}
```

I'm a bit unsure about how I dealt with the variable-length messages, especially the usage of placement new, without calling the destructor.

So, opinions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    enum message_type : signed char
```

Do you have a specific reason (e.g. protocol requirements?) that this be signed? Bit-level stuff usually involves unsigned types. The protocol specs also explicity mention the size of the message type field: a single byte. So I recommend `std::uint8_t` here.

```
    // A template definition for messages, templated on the message type.
    template <message_type Type>
        struct message {};
```

If only the specializations are meant to be used (I couldn't tell from looking at your code), I usually 'forbid' the base template to catch mistakes early. Errors about how `message<...>` has no `put` member are confusing and not necessarily near the code that instantiated the template. The simplest way to do it is to leave the template undefined but lately I've been using a trick: `static_assert( dependent_false<Type>::value, "Only specializations should be used" );`, where `dependent_false<T>::value` is always `false` but won't trigger the assert until instantiation (whereas `static_assert( false, ... )` always triggers and won't let you compile, ever.)

```
    template<>
        struct message<bitfield> : public variable_payload_message<message<bitfield>>
        {
        public:
            message() = delete;
            explicit message(std::string bits);

            const std::string payload() const;
```

I'd prefer returning `std::string` here. (Ditto for `message<piege>::payload`.)

```
    // A simple type trait that determines if a type is a message type
    template <typename NonMesssage>
        struct is_message : std::false_type {};
    template <message_type Type>
        struct is_message<message<Type>> : std::true_type {};
```

Lately I've been making my traits more convenient to use by adding forwarding specializations: `template<typename T> struct is_message<T&>: is_message<T> {};`, and another one for `const`. They help with perfect forwarding because if you have e.g. `template<typename M> void perfectly_forwarded(M&&);` then `M` might be `T const&` for some `T`. Since you're not doing that in your code I don't think you need it -- just a head's up.

```
    // Implementation of operator<< for all message types
    // This requires the put member function
    template <typename Message>
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, typename std::enable_if<is_message<Message>::value,const Message&>::type message);
```

Deduction can't work here. C++03-style code uses `enable_if` at the return type, or when there is no return type (e.g. constructors) as a default argument.  Maybe you tried to 'collapse' the default argument with the actual, interesting parameter, but you can't do that. C++0x-style code can put `enable_if` as a defaulted template parameters but that's moot since you really want (credit to CatPlusPlus):

```
template<message_type M>
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, message<M> const& m);
```

---

```
    // simple implementation of operator<< for messages
```

Change definition to match previous declaration.

```
    // implementation of no-payload message base class
    template <message_type Type>
        std::ostream& no_payload_message<Type>::put(std::ostream& os) const {
            // make sure this struct is not padded or anything
            // this is a gcc attribute, I'll change this when there is
            // support for the C++11 attribute alignas
            struct __attribute__ ((packed)) data_type {
                unsigned len;
                message_type type;
            };
            // hton is a function that converts from host-endianness to network-endianness
            data_type buffer = { hton(sizeof(data_type)-sizeof(data_type::len)), Type }; // lay out the length and the message type
            return os.write(static_cast<char*>(&buffer), sizeof(data_type)); // write it
        }
```

Again, following protocol specs, I'd make `len` a `std::uint32_t`. The unofficial spec use `1` as the length, I'm not sure what you're computing here. Minor note: I always write `os.write(static_cast<char*>(&buffer), sizeof buffer)` to future-proof (unlikely to matter here but still).

```
    // implementation of fixed-length payload message base class
    template <typename Message>
        std::ostream& fixed_payload_message<Message>::put(std::ostream& os) const {
            auto buffer = static_cast<const Message*>(this)->data(); // get the data from the derived class
            return os.write(static_cast<char*>(&buffer), sizeof(buffer)); // write it
        }
```

And in fact here you do take the size of the object!

```
    // implementation of variable-length payload message base class
    template <typename Message>
        std::ostream& variable_payload_message<Message>::put(std::ostream& os) const {
            typedef typename Message::data_type header_type;

            auto m = static_cast<const Message*>(this);
            const auto payload = m->payload(); // get the payload
            const auto data_type_size = sizeof(header_type)+payload.size(); // get the total size
            std::unique_ptr<char[]> mem(new char[data_type_size]); // allocate a buffer for it
            m->init(mem.get()); // write out the fixed-length portion
            std::copy(payload.begin(), payload.end(), mem.get()+sizeof(header_type)); // copy the payload to the buffer
            return os.write(mem.get(), data_type_size); // write it
        }
```

I don't see the need to copy the final message into a buffer. Why not use two calls to `ostream::write`? You could replace the `init` members (which you already dislike) with a `data` member like the fixed-length messages.

```
// Lots of definitions/instantiations
```

Again, I didn't check conformance to the specs. I also already mentioned to you how most of the explicit instantiations aren't needed.

I'd also write `sizeof field0 + sizeof field1 + ...` for computing the various sizes that you need rather than subtracting from the total size. I'd do that for clarity and I don't think it's a correctness issue however.

---

Final remarks on the general design:

I think you're somewhat abusing specializations here: there's is no need (IMO) for a `message` catch-all template since the three kinds of messages are not similar in use. This really shows I think with the constructors that aren't compatible: you can't write a generic `message<M> m(arguments go here);`. Personally I'd have used overloaded function templates to return those three types.

Also I personally typically use `std::vector<unsigned char>` for binary stuff rather than `std::string` but I don't think that really matters (plus you may have a use for some `std::string`-specific stuff that is not in the code you presented).

Answer (score 0):

Can't really complain about most of it.

The only thing I dislike is the abuse of auto:

```
        auto m = static_cast<const Message*>(this);
        const auto payload = m->payload(); // get the payload
        const auto data_type_size = sizeof(header_type)+payload.size(); // get the total size
```

You know what the types are so why not be specific (personally I think that will make the code easier to read).

Comment: If that's an abuse of the auto keyword, whats the intended use?

Comment: Its intend use is places where the type is a really complex template and you dont actually need or want to know. Like iterators or functrs retrieved from complex template objects: `for(auto it = plop.being(); it != plop.end(); ++it){}` Here all you need to know is that it is an iterator the exact type is not important. Above the exact type is 1) important 2) Easy to deduce. `m` is a message and being used as one. `data_type_size` is a `size_t`

Comment: I disagree that code sprinkled with types is easier to read. Type inference is a good thing.

Comment: @Cat: At this point me advice is just a personal opinion. Thats why I dislike rather than saying there is anything wrong. But please chime into this conversation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6900459/14065

Comment: @Martin The intent of templates is to allow generic containers. So please don’t abuse templates for metaprogramming.